# Populate TextBox with the Sql query that was ran

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a request I think should be simple but for some reason I can't get it to work. I have a button that is clicked and runs a query and populates my datagridview. I want to populate a textbox with that exact query that is ran so a user could modify it. Here is the code below.

```
private void SHTTBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionBox.Text))
        {
            var SHTTCmd = new SqlCommand("Do some SQL Command");
            SHTTCmd.Connection = myConnection;
            SHTTCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter SqlSHTTAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(SHTTCmd);
            DataTable SHTTRecord = new DataTable();
            SqlSHTTAdap.Fill(SHTTRecord);
            ClientInfoDGV.DataSource = SHTTRecord;
            ManualQueryBox.Text = SHTTCmd.ToString();
        }      
    }
```

The result I get in the ManualQueryBox.Text is "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand"

Comment: "Do some SQL Command" should come from a TextBox.Text property.  In the grand scheme of things, this is a bad idea.  You are giving your users keys to the kingdom, and they would be able to delete tables, etc.  Give the user filter options instead.

Comment: The connection string is for a read only database.

Comment: From your posted code, try `ManualQueryBox.Text = SHTTCmd.CommandText;`

Comment: Beautiful! You should submit that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `form_load` you would do this:

```
ManualQueryBox.Text = "your sql command";
```

Then, afterwards, on the button click, you would do this:

```
var SHTTCmd = new SqlCommand(ManualQueryBox.Text);
```

Of course, this is unsafe as hell depending on what you're trying to do. But that's basically how you get the query from a textbox.

**OR**

if you just want to get the query text from the command, instead of

```
ManualQueryBox.Text = SHTTCmd.ToString();
```

you would do

```
ManualQueryBox.Text = SHTTCmd.CommandText;
```

Comment: But I have multiple buttons with multiple sql queries. Also doing that on form load would populate that textbox prior to the button even being clicked. I want it to be populated after clicking the button. I have an execute button next to the textbox so they can run it that way afterwards if they want to change anything around.